# uiview.trailing = trailing not working in landscape

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I want a textfield to extend (almost) all the way to the trailing margin. It works perfectly in portrait, but when I rotate to landscape, the textfield doesn't extend as far as I've specified.

[Here is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYxPw.jpg)

[and here is how it looks in landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcqGl.jpg)

As you can see, the textfield doesn't extend to all the way to the trailing margin + 44.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: When you run the app - do you have any comment about the constraints in the log?

Comment: no, none @GalMarom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These fields are in a scroll view, which is causing this. The scrollview starts with the default values in Interface Builder, and then the scrollview prefers to shrink it's `contentSize` rather than expand the text field. Set the scrollview's background color to something and you'll see this.

Making one axis of a scrollview fixed to the frame,  size of the scrollview for one-dimensional scrolling is surprisingly hacky for something that scroll view clients want probably 90% of the time. The reason is that superview constraints in IB act on the scrollview's *frame*, which is what you want to size the frame, *but* there's no way in IB to constrain a superview to the scroll view's content size.

To make the scroll view scroll in one direction, first get the two items on either side that have constraints to the scrollview margins. In your case, the `UILabel` `leading` and `UITextField` `trailing`. Add constraints connecting them identically to the topmost UIView in the hierarchy. They will then hold the sides of the scrollview into place.

Comment: Ok thanks! How do I constrain them to the View? With the "add new constraints" pop-up I can only constrain them to the scrollview

Comment: Use the "document outline" (the list of objects that starts "View Controller Scene". From this you can control-drag to create constraints between the topmost view and the scrollview subviews.